# java regex split string by multiple chars and spaces

Tags: java

I have a string, i need to split by chars and spaces. it can be 1 or more of chars/spaces..can be any number of chars.

```
String a="1a2bc3 4d5      6ads";

s.split(" ");
```

I want 1 2 3 4 5 6.
do advise how incorporated the characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a streamlined regex splitting solution:

```java
String input = "1a2bc3 4d5      6ads";
String[] nums = input.split("\\D+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The idea here is to split the input one groups of one or more non digit characters.  This turns out an array consisting only of numbers, which were spared during the split.